# Can I store SQL statements in a separate file in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I would like to store all my SQL statements in a separate (`.txt` maybe?) file. This will make my code look clean and more readable.

**Example:**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

var sql = // get SQL from a file

connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
    var row;

    if (!err) {
        row = rows[0];
    }

    res.render('index', { ... });
})

});
```

P.S. I don't want to store the SQL statements in a `.js` file.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, you can do File I/O in node.js (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)
and Yes, you can extract your SQL from there and execute them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely can do that but remember that work with files cost "too much time". What you probably need is a layer that do that queries.

For example you could do something like:

```
  myDBLayer.getNumber(function(id, country, name){
    //Do stuff
  });
```

But you have to define the `getNumber` function and do a function for every query you want. Off course you can receive parameters and be a kind of abstract with that but I think that is more efficient that just read some file with all queries.

Answer (score 3):

> You surely can do that but remember that work with files cost "too
>   much time"

I don't agree with Gepser. File content should be loaded once at server start and being stored in ram (object I mean) while runtime.

I would separate queries into some logical modules and then into tables or at least just tables:

**json file**:

```json
{
  "usersTable": {
    "selectAll": "select * from user",
    "selectSome": "select * from users where id > :id",
    "insert": "insert into users values (:name, :second_name, )"
  },
  "messagesTable": {
    "selectAll": ""
  }
}
```

**key-value file**:

```
usersTable.selectAll=select * from user
userTable.selectSome=select * from users where id > :id
userTable.insert=insert into users values (:name, :second_name, )

messagesTable.selectAll=
```

- If the project is huge you dont want to store every single query in
  one file. At least with key-value approach. Separate files by directories that contain module name.
- Use named parameters instead of positional. Otherwise it's ambiguous what parameter is when you don't see the query.
- Load file with sqls at application initialization. And use object at runtime.